# Can certificates be extended and/or does the serial number change in that case?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I was wondering, if there is a way to **extend the duration of an existing certificate**.

- Or is simply a *new certificate* requested *for the old public key*?
- Is this mentioned somewhere in the certificate? (Someone told me that the trustworthiness of websites is rated on how often the extended the certificate)
- Does the **serial number change** in that case?
- What are reasons to use the old keypair instead of requesting a certificate for a new keyPair?

Comment: Why would you need to keep the same public key?  This doesn't make sense to me.  A certificate change is a new certificate, period.

Comment: You can use the same _private_ key if it's matching the required length 2048 bits. The serial number should change as it's not "extending" but "reissuing". There's no point of keeping old private key if you are issuing a new cert (there's technically no such thing as "extending", it's sales term only).

Comment: The main part is a duplicate of [How to extend x509 certificate validity](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91510/how-to-extend-x509-certificate-validity). Questions about keeping the key or not on renewal are answered in [Renew digital certificate](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/renew-digital-certificate).

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible as you would be reissuing the certificate. Your serial number will change.